# Xamarin.Forms drop down

Tags: android, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I am using a picker in Xamarin forms and it looks like a entry box on the page until you tap it and it choices popup. I want to visually tell the user that this is drop down which they can select from. Can I do it using styling? So body suggested using Effects. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/

This shows what the picker will render as across platforms. As you can see it does not give you an indication of a dropdown. From what I understand you would have to implement a custom renderer for each platform to add any kind of drop down arrow.

Comment: Also, if you haven't looked at them yet, here is a ton of information on Customer Renderers. They're awesome!

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately xamarin forms picker has simple features. I think try Custom renderer because if you want custom style or effect then use custom renderer and check below link.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs